# How Do I put lines in this Html page inline them?

Tags: html, css

I want lines of these 5 dive align with each other in both vertical and horizontal. how do I do this? I try to do this with add margin to divs, But I can't get a good result. I want something like this image. I want do this without using table tag.

[image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrZzE.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 <style>
  .d{
   width:980px;height:500px;margin:0 auto;
  }
  .d ul{
   list-style-type: none;padding:0;margin:0;
  }
  .d ul li{
   list-style-type: none;padding:0;
  }
  .d1{
   width:50%;height:100px;direction: rtl;border:solid 2px #1946E7;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box; 
  }
  .r{
   direction:rtl;
  } 
  .l{
   direction:ltr;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="d">
  <ul>
    <li class="l"><div class="d1"></div></li>
    <li class="r"><div class="d1"></div></li>
       <li class="l"><div class="d1"></div></li>
    <li class="r"><div class="d1"></div></li>
    <li class="l"><div class="d1"></div></li>
  </ul>
  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try This Code!!Hope This Work For you..
```

```css
.d{
   width:980px;height:500px;margin:0 auto;
  }
  .d ul{
   list-style-type: none;padding:0;margin:0;
  }
  .d ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -8px;
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .d1{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    direction: rtl;
    border: solid 10px #222223;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 50px 201px;
  }
  .r{
   direction:rtl;
  } 
  .l{
   direction:ltr;
  }
```

```html
<div class="d">
  <ul>
    <li class="l"><div class="d1"></div></li>
    <li class="r"><div class="d1"></div></li>
       <li class="l"><div class="d1"></div></li>
    <li class="r"><div class="d1"></div></li>
    <li class="l"><div class="d1"></div></li>
  </ul>
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this; Tables are great for organizing `<div>` elements.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 <style>
  .d{
   width:980px;height:500px;margin:0 auto;
  }
  .d ul{
   list-style-type: none;padding:0;margin:0;
  }
  .d ul li{
   list-style-type: none;padding:0;
  }
  .d1{
   width:50%;height:100px;direction: rtl;border:solid 2px #1946E7;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box; 
  }
  .r{
   direction:rtl;
  } 
  .l{
   direction:ltr;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="d">
  <table>
          <tbody>
    <tr><div class="d1"></div></tr>
    <tr><div class="d1"></div></tr>
       <tr><div class="d1"></div></tr>
    <tr><div class="d1"></div></tr>
    <tr><div class="d1"></div></tr>
          </tbody>
  </table>
  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```